# Mailing sent with wrong link

Tags: civimail

I've just realised I've sent an email out with a broken link.

Unfortunately it's munged in a way that means that I can't easily catch it with a drupal redirect.

I could probably figure out an nginx regex to match this - but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There is a way that doesn't involve nginx regex's (https://xkcd.com/208/)

If you are comfortable accessing your civicrm database directly you can locate the correct row in the civicrm_mailing_trackable_url and update the value of the url.

If you run

```
select id, url, mailing_id from civicrm_mailing_trackable_url where mailing_id = X;
```

Where X is the mailing id - you will get a list of urls for that mailing and you should be able to pick out the broken link and update it.